# Git restore files from HEAD and no content in the files

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, github

Good afternoon!

I have seemed to have done a mistake in git. I was trying to clone a repo so I could push a project code to the repo, but got an upstream error and did git pull which didn't work and I tried to revert back to my initial commit which deleted my files. I did get them recovered using git checkout HEAD [filename], but when I go to open the said file I get unable to open error on visual code studio, and there is no content.
I ran the git show command and it shows all of my files and their contents. I also ran the history command, but it doesn't show all of the commands I have made.
How do I recover the full file?

Comment: When I type nano [filename] it opens the file with the contents in the termial, I am now confused

Answer (score 0):

Turns out VScode was having an issue. Opened the project using sublime and all of the code is there.